# Filter out existing objects in an array of objects

Tags: reactjs

I don't think this is difficult, I just can't figure out the best way to do it. This function is creating an array, from a group of checkboxes. I then want to break up the array and create an array of objects, because each object can have corresponding data. How do I filter out existing `rolesInterestedIn.roleType`.

```
handleTypeOfWorkSelection(event) {
    const newSelection = event.target.value;
    let newSelectionArray;

    if(this.state.typeOfWork.indexOf(newSelection) > -1) {
      newSelectionArray = this.state.typeOfWork.filter(s => s !== newSelection)
    } else {
      newSelectionArray = [...this.state.typeOfWork, newSelection];
    }
    this.setState({ typeOfWork: newSelectionArray }, function() {
      this.state.typeOfWork.map((type) => {
        this.setState({
          rolesInterestedIn: this.state.rolesInterestedIn.concat([
            {
              roleType: type,
            }
          ])
        }, function() {
          console.log(this.state.rolesInterestedIn);
        });
      })
    });
  }
```

**UDPATE**

```
rolesInterestedIn: [
  {
    roleType: '',
    experienceYears: ''
  }
],
```

Comment: what's the issue with this code? is it not working as you expecting, it will be better if you provide sample data, what you are expecting and what the result this method is producing.

Comment: `rolesInterestedIn`creates new objects each time I select or unselect a checkbox. I don't want it to just `concat` I want it to check for duplicates then update if required, by adding or removing the selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because each time you do `setState` you are concatenating the new value to the prev one in rolesInterestedIn array. Add new value only when you are adding new item, otherwise remove the object from both the state variable typeOfWork and rolesInterestedIn.

Try this:

```
handleTypeOfWorkSelection(event) {
    const newSelection = event.target.value;
    let newSelectionArray, rolesInterestedIn = this.state.rolesInterestedIn.slice(0);

    if(this.state.typeOfWork.indexOf(newSelection) > -1) {
        newSelectionArray = this.state.typeOfWork.filter(s => s !== newSelection);
        rolesInterestedIn = rolesInterestedIn.filter(s => s.roleType !== newSelection)
    } else {
        newSelectionArray = [...this.state.typeOfWork, newSelection];
        rolesInterestedIn = newSelectionArray.map((workType) => {
            return {
                roleType: workType,
                experienceYears: '',
            }
        });
    }
    this.setState({
         typeOfWork: newSelectionArray,
         rolesInterestedIn: rolesInterestedIn  
    });
}
```

**Suggestion:** Don't use multiple setState within a function, do all the calculation then use setState once to update all the values in the last.

Comment: Cool. I don't think I'm implementing this correctly. Should this work with the update I've added?

Comment: need to change something, tell me one thing what will be the initial value of `experienceYears` with each roleType in `rolesInterestedIn` array?

Comment: Initial state will be null. The user will select it in another section.

Comment: yes it should work, check the updated answer, we need to add `experienceYears` also when adding the `roleTypes` :)

Comment: Unless I'm reading this wrong, this doesn't setState of `rolesInterestedIn`.

Comment: it will update the `rolesInterestedIn`, because `this.setState({rolesInterestedIn})` is same as `this.setState({rolesInterestedIn:rolesInterestedIn})`, try and let me know if it fails to solve your issue  :)

Comment: @bp123 glad, it solved your issue, updated the answer with your changes :)